# Is there a recommended way to skip first line of a CSV file in Moqui?

Tags: moqui

I have a CSV file generated by another programme that is uploaded to Moqui as a FileItem without any editing done on the CSV file.

So it has a header that I don't want to use, therefore I manually specify csvEntityName and csvFieldNames for the entity data loader. But the header is taken as the first record. - Is there a recommended way to skip the first line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging deeper, in EntityDataLoaderImpl.groovy we have:

```
CSVParser parser = CSVFormat.newFormat(edli.csvDelimiter)
                .withCommentMarker(edli.csvCommentStart)
                .withQuote(edli.csvQuoteChar)
                .withSkipHeaderRecord(true) // TODO: remove this? does it even do anything?
                .withIgnoreEmptyLines(true)
                .withIgnoreSurroundingSpaces(true)
                .parse(reader)
```

The reason .withSkipHeaderRecord(true) currently does nothing is you first have to specify that the file has a header to skip using .withHeader(). ( https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html#withFirstRecordAsHeader--)

If you add that, the .withSkipHeaderRecord(boolean) will skip the header record if passed 'true'.

(I think this needs to be made an issue, so I will do that.)